# jQuery if window location contains any of the given numbers

Tags: jquery, variables, window.location

I'm using a string in the window's location (`pid=xxx`) to determine what to append to do via jQuery.

This is the current jQuery I have:

```
var pid = 123;
if ( window.location.href.indexOf("pid=" + pid) > -1 ){
    // do something
}
```

The issue is that I want to list multiple numbers that the `pid` could be, such as 123, 456, or 789.

Basically, if the window.location contains `pid=123`, `pid=456`, or `pid=789`, then do something. I'm not sure if I'm looking for an array solution or not...

If anyone could offer some advice, it would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use an array:

```
var pid = [123, 456, 789];
for(var i = 0; i < pid.length; i++){
    if ( window.location.href.indexOf("pid=" + pid[i]) > -1 ){
        // do something
    }
}
```